# Embedding a google doc in a website: User comments are always anonymous in Chrome (but works in Firefox)

Tags: google-drive-api, google-docs

I am using the following code to embed google docs in my React + Asp.Net website

```
<iframe className="embed-responsive-item"
        src={`https://docs.google.com/document/d/${props.docid}/edit?rm=minimal&embedded=true`} />
```

The page is displayed fine. However, in Chrome the user is always shown as Anonymous when commenting on the document although they are signed in to Google Doc accounts. In Firefox, everything works fine and users' actual account names are displayed in the comments. If I open the `src` link in a new tab (in Chrome), then it works fine, users can comment with their actual Google Doc account.

I wonder if there is a way to overcome this problem for embedded google docs in Chrome.

Comment: The probably likely is the `iframe`, which does not get the credentials from the parent page.

Comment: yes but how to mitigate this? why is it working in other browsers?

Comment: Not certain about it, but when running `document.featurePolicy.allowedFeatures()`, there's also `document-domain`.... and `iframe` supports the `allow` attribute. See [Introduction to Feature Policy](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2018/06/feature-policy). But there are further attributes for `iframe`, which control the embedding. Either the issue is content security policy or feature policy related (don't know of other features which could prevent it). Firefox might only lack the security feature, supporting it in an insecure way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just figured out that the comments will not be anonymous (including in Chrome) if the users (editing or accessing the document) are invited through their gmail addresses. I hope this helps others.